# Deploying Redmine docker container to App Services

Tags: image, azure, docker, service, redmine

I would like to deploy Redmine Docker image to Azure App Services and point it to the MySql instance deployed to Azure Database for MySQL servers. This would give me a fully managed architecture. I have created an instance of MySql and can connect to it from my local PC using MySql Workbench. Unfortunately the Redmine Docker image I am deploying to App Services fails to start. The log says: Docker on instance ******* experienced container start failures. The application log indicates there is an issue with Startup Command. After reviewing the container crash logs I have noticed that my startup command is appended to the docker run command:

docker run -d -p 6390:3000 --name redminetest_0_3d4d8283 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=redminetest -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=3000 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=redminetest.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=c0f955200062b837a8b06271f039c1d9a6aa1309ada101b0e47bf9c23c0ba3a3 redmine:latest **--name MyRedmine -e REDMINE_DB_MYSQL=51.140.184.11 -e REDMINE_DB_PORT=3306 -e REDMINE_DB_USERNAME=special@mysqlredmine -e REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD=Sp3c1al! redmine**

I can see straight away that --name argument and image name/tag was duplicated by my command. This is something I can correct but how can I append my environment variables before the image name/tag (redmine:latest) ?

UPDATE:

Please see the screenshot below. This demonstrates the issue. My environment variables were appended after the image name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The correct format of `docker run` is below:-

```
Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

According to which you should pass Image Name in the end and all other options like `-p, -e, -d`, etc. should be pass before Image Name.

Below is the correct command:

```
docker run -d -p 6390:3000 --name redminetest_0_3d4d8283 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=redminetest -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=3000 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=redminetest.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=c0f955200062b837a8b06271f039c1d9a6aa1309ada101b0e47bf9c23c0ba3a3 -e REDMINE_DB_MYSQL=51.140.184.11 -e REDMINE_DB_PORT=3306 -e REDMINE_DB_USERNAME=special@mysqlredmine -e REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD=Sp3c1al! redmine:latest
```

Comment: This does not answer my question at all. I know what the correct format is. The problem is that Azure auto generates the docker run command based on user input. The wizard for App Services also allows you to specify Startup command but whatever i put there is appended to the auto generated docker run statement which simply breaks it. For example:  Azure App Service generates - docker run ... redmine, I specify Startup command - -e REDMINE_DB_MYSQL=51.140.184.11 -e REDMINE_DB_PORT=3306, the result of this is: docker run ... redmine -e REDMINE_DB_MYSQL=51.140.184.11 -e REDMINE_DB_PORT=3306.

Comment: Because it is appended after the image name the run statement fails to execute. So the question is what is the point of allowing people to provide Startup Arguments if it is appended after the image name. Is there a workaround?